# How to install Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, system-installation

I have downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 desktop. Now I can't open it to install it. Keep getting a request for which program to use to open it. How do I install it?

Comment: follow these steps https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make a bootable device.

Plug-in your USB memory stick.
Go to [www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer) and download the Universal-USB-Installer.exe file. Put it on your Desktop or somewhere convenient.

Double-click the file to run it.
Click I agree and you will be taken to the Setup Your Selections screen (Figure 1).

Under Step 1, choose the version of Ubuntu you have downloaded, and uncheck Download the ISO.
If your version is not in the list, return to www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer and download the latest version of the installer.

Under Step 2, click Browse and select and open the .iso file you downloaded earlier.

Under Step 3, select your memory stick from the list (make sure you choose the right one). Check the box next to the list to say that you want to format the drive.
Click Create to put the installer onto your memory stick. The whole process should only take a few minutes. All of the files on the memory stick will be erased.

When it has finished, close the Universal USB Installer window and safely remove/eject and unplug your memory stick. This is necessary to make sure all of the files were put on the memory stick properly.

Further details [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick)